# Angular In-Memory Web API with Embedded

Tags: angular, crud, angular-in-memory-web-api

I'm trying to use Angular In-Memory Web API. I have many API that are used as CRUD but the issue is that I have responses with embedded and pagination.

Here is an example of one of my CRUD:

```
readPage(externalId: string, page: number, size: number, sort: string, search: string): Observable<FooPage>;
```

The FooPage is declare like this:

```
export interface FooPage {
   embedded: {
      foos: Foo[]
   },
   _links: Link[],
   page: PageDetail
}
```

The readOne:

```
readOne(externalId: string, fooId: string): Observable<Foo>;
```

The create

```
createFoo(externalId: string, fooCreate: FooCreate): Observable<Foo>;
```

The update

```
updateFoo(externalId: string, fooId: string, fooUpdate: FooUpdate): Observable<Foo>;
```

Do you have any idea for using In-Memory Web API with this CRUD structure ?
Are any advice about using another mock library ?

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you have a specific problem or do you want a full solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using this method:

```
protected responseInterceptor(res: ResponseOptions, ri: RequestInfo): ResponseOptions;
```

Then in this method I just have to set the response body as follow:

```
res.body = {
  _embedded: {
    foos: res.body
  },
  page: {
    total_elements: foos.length
  }
} as FooPage;
```